# Counting results in MySQL with highest value by category

Tags: mysql, sorting, max, categories

Here is my `table`

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47e2d/8

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ id ║ category ║ userid ║ users ║ points ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║    2     ║  91    ║ user1 ║  100   ║
║ 2  ║    3     ║  92    ║ user2 ║   80   ║
║ 3  ║    4     ║  93    ║ user3 ║   10   ║
║ 4  ║    4     ║  91    ║ user1 ║   12   ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

How do I get the count result of users with the highest points per category?

In the above example, I want to get

```
user1: 2
user2: 1
```

After searching for similar problems in stackoverflow for some time, I came up with

```
SELECT users, COUNT(*) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE points=(SELECT MAX(points) FROM `table`) 
GROUP BY points;
```

But it does not produce what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT 
  users,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    users,
    COUNT(*) COUNT
  FROM
    `table` 
  WHERE points IN 
    (SELECT 
      MAX(points) 
    FROM
      `table` 
    GROUP BY category) 
  GROUP BY points) temp 
GROUP BY users ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t1.users,
  COUNT(t2.category)
FROM `table` AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT category, MAX(points) MAxpoints
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY category
) AS t2 ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.points = t2.MAxpoints
GROUP BY t1.users;
```

The joined subquery:

```
  SELECT category, MAX(points) MAxpoints
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY category
```

will give you the max `points` for each category, then we get those users of those max points, by joining that subquery with the orginal table, then we use the `COUNT` to count those categories of the max points for each user.

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47e2d/27)

This will give you:

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║ USERS  ║ COUNT ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ user1  ║     2 ║
║ user2  ║     1 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT users, count(*) 
FROM `TABLE`, 
  (SELECT category, max(points) as max_points FROM `TABLE` GROUP BY category) as maxes
WHERE maxes.category = `TABLE`.category AND maxes.max_points = `TABLE`.points
GROUP BY users
```

The key here is creating a temporary table that contains the max points for each category

```
SELECT category, max(points) as max_points FROM `TABLE` GROUP BY category
```

Which I then use to join with the existing `TABLE` to find the correct user who has the maximum points.